# Plunge router base plate has a bit sticking out - why?

Tags: router

I just got a router and there's a plate on the bottom (required for the dust extractor attachment) which has a hole in it with a raised circular wall that protrudes beyond the level of the base. Is this normal? It seem like it will get in the way, but I don't want to do anything about it if it's supposed to be there.

[image]

Comment: This is referred to as a bushing or guide bushing (occasionally a collar), used for various routing tasks that involve templates of one form or another. It should be described clearly in the documentation that came with the router, although it will only give you a hint as to how it can be used.

Comment: .. and, to build on @Graphus answer: it can be taken out when it's not used.

Comment: Thanks @Graphus, if you post that as answer I can tick it

Comment: Does the guide bushing on the silver metal plate need to come out? It almost looks like the black plastic plate might be the same thickness as the guide bushing, and that you could take off the plastic plate when you wanted to use the bushing. I could be wrong though. *ETA: Ahh, this is old. Just caught that. But still!*

Comment: For future readers: If that is indeed the case, leaving the bushing on might be preferable, because the bushing has to be exactly centered on the router bit for template routing to work with a guide bushing. It might be easier to take the plastic part off and leave the bushing on. Presumably the plastic part is less picky about being dead center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From the comments:**

This is referred to as a bushing or guide bushing (occasionally a collar), used for various routing tasks that involve templates of one form or another. It should be described clearly in the documentation that came with the router, although it will only give you a hint as to how it can be used.

Comment: Busy work to get more only-answered-in-the-comments Q&A sorted.